# MySQL database SSL connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mysql-connect

I have a database setup non remote server.

What im trying to do is establish the connection using PHP.

All the settings on the server are OK as I tested it using MySQL workbench using following details:
Hostname : xxx.xx.xx.xxx Port - blank so as defalut this is :3306

In advanced tab in workbench "Use SSL if available" is selected. Connection test is successful.

Although when Im trying to connect using simple mysq_connect('IP','user','pass') im getting the following errors:
line 2 : $c = mysql_connect('IP','USER','PASS');

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Premature end of
> data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:553) in C:\wamp\www\sql\index.php on line
>
> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: OK packet 1 bytes shorter than expected >in C:\wamp\www\sql\index.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in C:\wamp\www\sql\index.php on line 2

Its been days now when Im trying to establish this connection. Please help!

Comment: Did you reset you password as instructed there at the bottom?

Comment: No, I didn't but why would it connect using MySQL workbench?

Comment: Dom, this error could cause even if there's a version incompaitibility b/w your mysql and PHP. Which version(s) you are in?

Answer (score 1):

try..

```
mysql_connect('IP','USER','PASS', false, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
```

Comment: I tried that. Now I have the following error Warning: mysql_connect() [streams.crypto]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\wamp\www\sql\index.php on line 2

Comment: Do you have the php_openssl extension up and running?  http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Quick guide:

1. Open the server's `my.cnf` (usually in `/etc`)
2. Comment out the `old-passwords = 1`
3. Restart MySQL
4. Run `mysql_fix_privilege_tables` if necessary
5. Connect using the `mysqlclient` utility as `root`
6. `use mysql`
7. `update user set password=password('new password') where user='the user'`

Then try again

Comment: There is nothing in /etc apart from php5/php.ini

Comment: @Dom well, check the output of `SELECT PASSWORD('test');` and make sure it's ehh ... long :) if not, you will have to look for the `my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

here you are [php manual mysql connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

see client flags